# SQL Server Client Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, ssl

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.

> (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Please note, i can connect this server remotely and connect to SQL server with my credentials, but SSMS is giving this error, as well i can connect to another SQL server from the SSMS on the same system.

I have tried many basic post on stackoverflow, restart the server my system done.
Seems like the issue with SSL or TLS connectivity with this server

Comment: Will you please add the code which were you tried therefore you can get better help

Comment: >>>i can connect this server remotely and connect to SQL server with my credentials, but SSMS is giving this error<<< What does it mean? How do you connect remotely, not via SSMS?

Comment: I can connect to server through remote desktop connection and then connect to SQL server with my credentials, but when from my local machine i try to connect SQL Server through SSMS using my credentials it gives the error (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: Please help if any solution suggested